# Bad state: No method stub was called from within `when()`. Was a real method called, or perhaps an extension method? flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in TDD. I am writing a test for bloc in flutter and getting an error in the when method.

```
import 'package:bloc_test/bloc_test.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:weather_clean_architecture_tdd/presentation/bloc/weather_bloc.dart';
import 'package:weather_clean_architecture_tdd/presentation/screens/weather_page.dart';

class MockWeatherBloc extends MockBloc<WeatherEvent, WeatherState>
    implements WeatherBloc {}

class FakeWeatherState extends Fake implements WeatherState {}

class FakeWeatherEvent extends Fake implements WeatherEvent {}

void main() {
  late MockWeatherBloc mockWeatherBloc;

  setUp(() => mockWeatherBloc = MockWeatherBloc());

  Widget makeTestableWidget(Widget body) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => mockWeatherBloc,
      child: MaterialApp(home: body),
    );
  }

  testWidgets(
    'text field trigger state to change from empty to loading',
    (widgetTester) async {
      // Arrange
      when(() => mockWeatherBloc.state).thenReturn(() => WeatherEmpty());

      // Act
      await widgetTester.pumpWidget(makeTestableWidget(const WeatherPage()));
      var textField = find.byType(TextField);
      expect(textField, findsOneWidget);
      await widgetTester.enterText(textField, 'Karachi');
      await widgetTester.pump();
      expect(find.text('Karachi'), findsOneWidget);
    },
  );
}
```

This is the error message I am getting
Bad state: No method stub was called from within `when()`. Was a real method called, or perhaps an
extension method?

I tried importing when of mocktail but still same error is being thrown.
I am expecting the test case to pass.

Comment: Should it be just `when(mockWeatherBloc.state` without making it to a function call?

Comment: I tried that
then getting error ```The argument type 'WeatherEmpty Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'WeatherState'.```

Comment: The value for `thenReturn` must also be changed, it can’t be a function

Comment: When I tried ```when(mockWeatherBloc.state).thenReturn(WeatherEmpty());``` it throws another error ```The following _TypeError was thrown running a test: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'WeatherState'```.

Furthermore, I tried mocktail method ```when(() => mockWeatherBloc.state).thenReturn(WeatherEmpty());```, it throws the error ```The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#ad930]:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<WeatherBloc> above this BlocBuilder<WeatherBloc,WeatherState> Widget```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
when(() => mockWeatherBloc.stream)
    .thenAnswer((_) => const Stream.empty());
when(() => mockWeatherBloc.state).thenAnswer((_) =>WeatherEmpty()));
when(() => mockWeatherBloc.close()).thenAnswer((_) async {});
```

instead of

```
when(() => mockWeatherBloc.state).thenReturn(() => WeatherEmpty());
```

Comment: This still shows 3 errors in the compiler: 1. `The return type 'Stream<dynamic>' isn't a 'Stream<WeatherState> Function()', as required by the closure's context`, 2. `The return type 'WeatherInitial' isn't a 'WeatherState Function()', as required by the closure's context` and 3. `The argument type 'Future<Null> Function(Invocation)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<void> Function() Function(Invocation)'`

Answer (score 0):

You've imported the `mockito` instead of `mocktail` like I did.

1. replace this:

```
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
```

**with**

```
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';
```

2. set `thenReturn` argument to be your `WeatherEmpty` instance:

```
when(() => mockWeatherBloc.state).thenReturn(WeatherEmpty());
```

3. Run your test.

your test should pass ✅  Disclaimer: If it doesn't, check the `mocktail` version you're using. I'm using ^1.0.3 and it works fine.

---

Also, you don't need this:

```
class FakeWeatherState extends Fake implements WeatherState {}

class FakeWeatherEvent extends Fake implements WeatherEvent {}
```

---

Here's your full code from the question, just edited:

```
import 'package:bloc_test/bloc_test.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';
import 'package:weather_clean_architecture_tdd/presentation/bloc/weather_bloc.dart';
import 'package:weather_clean_architecture_tdd/presentation/screens/weather_page.dart';

class MockWeatherBloc extends MockBloc<WeatherEvent, WeatherState>
    implements WeatherBloc {}

void main() {
  late MockWeatherBloc mockWeatherBloc;

  setUp(() => mockWeatherBloc = MockWeatherBloc());

  Widget makeTestableWidget(Widget body) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => mockWeatherBloc,
      child: MaterialApp(home: body),
    );
  }

  testWidgets(
    'text field trigger state to change from empty to loading',
    (widgetTester) async {
      // Arrange
      when(() => mockWeatherBloc.state).thenReturn(WeatherEmpty());

      // Act
      await widgetTester.pumpWidget(makeTestableWidget(const WeatherPage()));
      var textField = find.byType(TextField);
      expect(textField, findsOneWidget);
      await widgetTester.enterText(textField, 'Karachi');
      await widgetTester.pump();
      expect(find.text('Karachi'), findsOneWidget);
    },
  );
}
```